# Iterating over SearchResultCollection is Very Slow

Tags: asp.net, performance, foreach, ldap, ldap-query

I'm running an LDAP query that returns multiple entries and stores them inside a SearchResultCollection.  I'm iterating over the SearchResultCollection like so:

```
// results is my SearchResultCollection object
foreach (SearchResult sr in results)  
{
    ... do things to each SearchResult in here ...
}
```

This seems like the most logical way to do this, but loop is *incredibly* slow.  When I step through the loop with the debugger, I find that it's the very first step of initializing the foreach loop that takes the time - the actual iterations are instantaneous.

In addition, when I view the contents of the SearchResultCollection while debugging, the watch takes just as long to load the contents of the variable.

I have a theory that the SearchResultCollection doesn't actually contain complete SearchResult objects, but rather references to entries in the Active Directory server that are then individually fetched when I iterate over the SearchResultCollection object.  Can anyone confirm this theory?  And is there a better (faster) way to fetch a set of LDAP entries?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There may be some ways to decrease the response time:

- restrict the scope of the search
- use a more restrictive search filter
- use a base object closer to the object(s) being retrieved.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)
- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the actual LDAP search takes almost no time at all.  The delay is introduced when I try and iterate over the resulting SearchResultCollection object.

Answer (score 2):

I suffered from the same problem and the methodology in the post below was much quicker then my own:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180881(v=vs.80).aspx

... to answer you question yes it seems as if you try to process the entries directly while still in the loop by using something like:

```
     If Not UserAccount.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("sAMAccountName").Value Is Nothing Then sAMAccountName = UserAccount.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0).ToString()
```

... this has a drastic impact on performance, you can get around this by adding the collection to a Dictionary within the loop and then processing the dictionary:

```
    Dim searchResult As SearchResult
    Dim dictLatestLogonDatesTemp As New Dictionary(Of String, Date)
    SearchResults1 = mySearcher.FindAll()
    For Each searchResult In SearchResults1
        Dim propertyKey,sAMAccountName  As String
        Dim dteLastLogonDate As Date = Nothing
        For Each propertyKey In searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames
            Dim valueCollection As ResultPropertyValueCollection = searchResult.Properties(propertyKey)
            For Each propertyValue As Object In valueCollection
                If LCase(propertyKey) = LCase("sAMAccountName") Then sAMAccountName = propertyValue
                If LCase(propertyKey) = LCase("lastLogon") Then dteLastLogonDate = Date.FromFileTime(propertyValue)
            Next propertyValue
        Next propertyKey
        If sAMAccountName <> Nothing Then dictLatestLogonDatesTemp.Add(sAMAccountName, dteLastLogonDate)
    Next searchResult
```

It is a bit restrictive bacause a dictionary ony has two entries but you can comma seperate other values or use a dictionary of values in the dictionary:

```
    Dim tempDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to submit that adding them to a datatable also works very well and allows for more properties than a dictionary. I went from iterating 2000 users in the searchresultscollection taking almost 2 minutes to less that 1-2 seconds. Hope this helps others.

```
  Private Sub getAllUsers()
    Dim r As SearchResultCollection
    Dim de As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(GetCurrentDomainPath)
    Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher(de)

    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID")
    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" '(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2) not disabled users 

    PleaseWait.Status("Loading Users...")
    Application.DoEvents()

    r = ds.FindAll()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("SID")

    For Each sr As SearchResult In r
        Dim SID As New SecurityIdentifier(CType(sr.Properties("objectSID")(0), Byte()), 0)
        dt.Rows.Add(sr.Properties("name")(0).ToString(), SID.ToString)
    Next

    With lstResults
        lstResults.DataSource = dt
        .DisplayMember = "name"
        .ValueMember = "SID"
        .Items.Sort()
    End With

End Sub
```